# Python Dictionary to JSON file conversion problem

Tags: python, json

so i've been working on a project that scrapes a finance site and saves the top 5 fastest changing stocks in a json file for later usage. My Problem is it doesn't format it right.

Function that converts it to JSON:

```
def writeToJSON(num, short, name, price, change):
stocks = {}
numStock = {
    "Short" : short,
    "Name" : name,
    "Price" : price,
    "Change" : change
    }


stocks.update({str(num) : numStock,})
with open(".\\sstocksim\\stocks.json", "a") as f:
    json.dump(stocks, f, indent=3)
    f.close()
```

JSON Output:

```
 {
   "1": {
      "Short": "AXSM",
      "Name": "Axsome Therapeutics, Inc.",
      "Price": "81.64",
      "Change": "+34.85"
   }
}{
   "2": {
      "Short": "TSLA",
      "Name": "Tesla, Inc.",
      "Price": "381.44",
      "Change": "+23.05"
   }
}{
   "3": {
      "Short": "CGX.TO",
      "Name": "Cineplex Inc.",
      "Price": "33.83",
      "Change": "+9.82"
   }
}{
   "4": {
      "Short": "MIRM",
      "Name": "Mirum Pharmaceuticals, Inc.",
      "Price": "17.17",
      "Change": "+8.98"
   }
}{
   "5": {
      "Short": "AMGN",
      "Name": "Amgen Inc.",
      "Price": "244.51",
      "Change": "+7.77"
   }
}
```

For some reason it puts an EOF after every entry and I can't figure out how to stop it from doing that.
Thanks in advance!!

EDIT:

You probably know how its supposed to look but just in case, thats the output i want:

```
{
   "1": {
      "Short": "AXSM",
      "Name": "Axsome Therapeutics, Inc.",
      "Price": "81.64",
      "Change": "+34.85"
   },

   "2": {
      "Short": "TSLA",
      "Name": "Tesla, Inc.",
      "Price": "381.44",
      "Change": "+23.05"
   },

   "3": {
      "Short": "CGX.TO",
      "Name": "Cineplex Inc.",
      "Price": "33.83",
      "Change": "+9.82"
   },

   "4": {
      "Short": "MIRM",
      "Name": "Mirum Pharmaceuticals, Inc.",
      "Price": "17.17",
      "Change": "+8.98"
   },

   "5": {
      "Short": "AMGN",
      "Name": "Amgen Inc.",
      "Price": "244.51",
      "Change": "+7.77"
   }
}
```

Comment: If your data set isn't massive, try reading the old json into an object, updating the object then writing the whole thing to a file

Comment: Welcome to SO! Consider using a list instead of a dict with sequentially increasing integer keys which is an antipattern.

Comment: The problem isn't the EOF as such, it's that you're appending individual JSON objects into the file without some overall structure.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing to the file once per `numStock`; that is, when you write the file, `stocks` contains a single item, which is the current `numStock`.

Instead, create a `stocks` dictionary that contains all of your `numStock` items, then write that to file.